# Как отличить объект события от DOM объекта? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, объекты, типы-данных, обработка-ошибок

Всем привет!
В метод может придти как dom-объект(не пинайте за терминологию):

```
<div class="parent" data-listener="not-add">...</div>
```

А может придти объект события:

```
MouseEvent{isTruste: true....}
```

Вопрос - как отличить их между собой? `typeof` в обоих случаях возвращает тип `object` и оба объекта не общих функций, по которым их можно было бы отличить, например: `.hasAttribute`, с помощью которого я мог бы проверить имеет ли объект атрибут `data-listener` не работает на объекте события и возвращает ошибку.
Есть какой-нибудь стандартный способ, чтобы мне не ловить ошибки/исключения и не выдумывать громоздкие костыли?
Спасибо!

Comment: Что-то совсем не понятно. Покажите, что Вы конкретно сравниваете?

Comment: `[ваш_объект] instanceof Node` - вернет `true`, если это блок.

Comment: `if (domElement.hasAttribute) { domElement.hasAttribute(...); }`